# How can I make my flex columns have equal height in an absolutely positioned container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have absolutely positioned `div.container`. `div.wrapper` inside it. and two divs as flex columns in `div.wrapper`. These columns have backgrounds.

How can I make these backgrounds go to the end of the longest column (i.e. make them the same height) and not only to the visible height of the container? I can't remove `position: absolute` from `div.container`.

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}
.div1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.div2 {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1">
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
            <p>Some long content here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
            <p>Some even longer content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvqWwg)

Comment: you need to remove `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` from the container styles, your wrapper already has flex - updated codepen https://codepen.io/kejt/pen/EvdyQy

Comment: Thank you, Kejt. But now if the content is short (it is dynamic), it will not take all the available space, like here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKybvK. Is there a way to keep this feature?

Comment: you can try add `min-height: 100vh;` to your container and wrapper https://codepen.io/kejt/pen/gxBgOG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the flex properties on the `container`.

I also removed `align-items: stretch; width: 100%;` from the `.wrapper` as it is their default value's and doesn't need to be set.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*  commented out these 2 lines
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  */
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /*  commented out these 2 lines as they are not needed
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
  */
}

.div1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">
      <p>Some long content here</p>
      <p>Some long content here</p>
      <p>Some long content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
      <p>Some even longer content here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```